# Trouble mapping Ajax to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jquery-ui-autocomplete

### Short version:

I need to know what to put here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orgSearch').autocomplete({
        // what do I put for "source" ???
        source : '/getOrgsViaAjax'
    });
});
```

and here:

```
// What do I put for the arguments in `@RequestMapping` ?
// What do I put as the arguments for the method?
// What do I name the method?

@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
    ...
}
```

to get my Ajax autocomplete to work with a Spring MVC controller.

---

### Long version:

I am trying to map Ajax autocomplete `source` tag with my Spring MVC controller, and I am unable to get anything to work.

What I've tried:

I have a Spring MVC controller that is similar to this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/PersonAffiliations.html")
public class PersonAffiliationsController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {

        System.out.println("getOrgsViaAjax -- Here");
        return "{\"Test OrgOne\":\"42695847\",\"Test OrgTwo\":\"84920493\",\"Test OrgThree\":\"22222222\",\"Test OrgFour\":\"42226589\"}";
    }

    // The controller methods below all work
    // I included them here just incase they're causing my issues
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPerson(Map model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        return "PersonAffiliations";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid PersonForm objPersonForm, BindingResult result, Map model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        return "PersonAffiliations";            
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processNameForm(@Valid PersonAffiliationForm objPersonAffiliationForm, BindingResult result, Map model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        return "PersonAffiliations";            
    }

}
```

And a .jsp page that is similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<html>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log("here");
            console.log('${pageContext.request.contextPath}');

            $('#orgSearch').autocomplete({
                source : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations/getOrgsViaAjax'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <head>
        <title>Person Affiliation Editor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form name="AddPersonAffiliationForm" action="PersonAffiliations.html" modelAttribute="BlankPersonAffiliationForm">
            ...
            <form:input id="orgDeptId" path="deptId" />
            <form autocomplete="off" id="searchOrgForm">
                <div class="autocomplete">
                    <input id="orgSearch" type="text" style="width:500px" name="orgSearch" placeholder="Organization" />
                </div>
            </form>


        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the `getOrgsViaAjax` controller method never executes. Firebug says `404`.

On the .jsp side I've tried:

```
source : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations/getOrgsViaAjax'

source : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations//getOrgsViaAjax'

source : '/PersonAffiliations/getOrgsViaAjax'

source : '/getOrgsViaAjax'

source : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax'

source : '/PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax'
```

On the controller side I've tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {


@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax")
public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {


@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax")
public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax() {
```

But I can't seem to get anything right.

Firebug makes it clear that when I type anything into the input field (to be autocompleted), it is sending a request, but it always comes back `404`:

[image]

So it's clear that the autocomplete function is firing a request, but it's not mapped to the MVC controller

How do you get the `source` to match the `RequestMapping` in Spring MVC?

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I should note that there is a `mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml` that looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <bean name="/SearchPerson.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.SearchPersonController" />      

    <bean name="/authenticate.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.LogInController" />

    <bean name="/PersonSummary.html"
            class="org.personhub.controller.PersonSummaryController" />

    <bean name="/ManagePerson.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.ManagePersonController" />

    <bean name="/PersonNames.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.PersonNamesController" />

    <bean name="/PartyAddresses.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.PartyAddressesController" />

    <bean name="/PartyIdentifiers.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.PartyIdentifiersController" />

    <bean name="/PersonAffiliations.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.PersonAffiliationsController" />

    <bean name="/PartyContactMethods.html" 
        class="org.personhub.controller.PartyContactMethodsController" />

    <bean name = "Logout.html"
         class= "org.personhub.controller.LogOutController"> </bean>    

      <!--  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->
     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">  
        <property name="definitions">  
            <list>  
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  


</beans>
```

---

Edit:

As requested, here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>PersonHubWeb</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>LogIn.jsp</welcome-file>              
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PersonHubStart</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.personhub.utils.StartUpServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>     
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>      

</web-app>
```

And just incase, here's the tiles.xml also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
  "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/pages/BaseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Person Hub UI" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/Baseheader.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/pages/BaseMenu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="feedback" value="/WEB-INF/pages/BaseFeedback.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/Basefooter.jsp" />
    </definition>


    <definition name="Search" template="/WEB-INF/pages/SearchLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Person Hub UI" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/SearchHeader.jsp" />     
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/Basefooter.jsp" />
    </definition>   

    <definition name="PersonSearch" extends="Search">               
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/SearchPerson.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PersonSummary" extends="base.definition">         
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PersonSummary.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="ManagePerson" extends="base.definition">      
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/ManagePerson.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PersonNames" extends="base.definition">       
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PersonNames.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PersonAffiliations" extends="base.definition">        
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PersonAffiliations.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PartyContactMethods" extends="base.definition">       
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PartyContactMethods.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PartyAddresses" extends="base.definition">

        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PartyAddresses.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="PartyIdentifiers" extends="base.definition">

        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/PartyIdentifiers.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: You are mapping a `/PersonAffiliations.html` but requesting to `/PersonAffiliations`, is that the intended request?

Comment: I've tried changing all of those (removing / adding `.html` to the `source` and `mapping`) but none of that works

Comment: can you show the web.xml ? why are you defining the beans in the xml ? Can you remove beans and  add `<context:component-scan base-package="name of the root package" />`  &  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
in dispatcher xml for component scanning to load the beans in the spring context ? Is this the only controller request that is not working for you ?

Comment: @Veeram I posted the web.xml. Why am I defining the beans in the xml? Well, I wasn't the one who built this so I'm not sure why the original architect of the app decided to do it that way (and asking him will be difficult). Yes this is the only controller request not working for me.

Comment: Can you remove the `@RequestMapping("/PersonAffiliations.html")` from class level and try source as `'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at set up you provided closely it appears your app is set up one way (web mvc) and you are tying to use it another way (rest web service).

You have to make few changes to make your application restful.

Create a new controller annotated with `@RestController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/personAffiliations")
public class PersonAffiliationsRestController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
     return "{\"Test OrgOne\":\"42695847\",\"Test OrgTwo\":\"84920493\",\"Test OrgThree\":\"22222222\",\"Test OrgFour\":\"42226589\"}";
   }
}
```

Register the controller in the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<bean name="/personAffiliations" class="org.personhub.controller.PersonAffiliationsRestController" />
```

Register a new url mapping for rest web services in `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>     
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Change source to use

```
'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/rest/personAffiliations/getOrgsViaAjax'
```

Comment: Ok. When adding the `url-pattern` to the `web.xml`, it throws an error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. No child element is expected at this point.`

Comment: I see. Can you update your web.xml to use servlet 3.0 ? Something like `<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`

Comment: Great. Please make sure when you deploy it to higher environment the application server supports 3.0 servlet spec. Tomcat 7 does that is where I tested the code.

Comment: I am deploying on an IBM WAS server. My local dev environment should match the destination server.

Comment: Also, actually, I was able to get it to work without the 3.0 spec by splitting the `servlet-mapping`

Comment: So instead of one `servlet-mapping` with two `url-pattern`s, there are two `servlet-mapping`s with one `url-pattern` each

Comment: That is the workaround for lower servlet versions I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You register a servlet with "*.html" then so your servlet dispatcher only *.html suffix requests. That's why your other mapping methods work well. Because you have class level mapping `@RequestMapping("/PersonAffiliations.html")` and it ends with .html suffix.

But when you use `@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax")` then your url become `PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax`. This doesn't end with *.html pattern. So it occurs 404 error.

**Possible Solution**

You add .html suffix both spring and autocomplete url as follows:

```
source : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax.html'

@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgsViaAjax.html")
public @ResponseBody String getOrgsViaAjax(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your mapping to `@RequestMapping("/PersonAffiliations")`.

You are currently requesting to `/PersonAffiliations/getOrgsViaAjax` instead of `/PersonAffiliations.html/getOrgsViaAjax`

Comment: Change the `@RequestMapping` on the class level? Or on the method level?

Comment: I added the `mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml` to clarify why the class has `@RequestMapping("/PersonAffiliations.html")`